# Celery does not receives tasks but it executes them sometime (unexpected random conNection loss with RabbitMQ)

Tags: docker, asynchronous, rabbitmq, celery, celery-task

I have a docker image of RabbitMQ running (port 5672) and connected to a celery worker. (I run celery -A app.worker worker --loglevel=INFO --pool=eventlet --without-heartbeat)
I have multiple tasks in this worker and they run most of the time fine. However, sometimes when I haven't used it for too long or in unexpected times, it stops receiving tasks. When I check the logs, celery still shows

```
Connected to amqp://guest:**@127.0.0.1:5672//
[2023-08-03 09:31:44,638: INFO/MainProcess] mingle: searching for neighbors
[2023-08-03 09:31:45,657: INFO/MainProcess] mingle: all alone
[2023-08-03 09:31:45,669: INFO/MainProcess] pidbox: Connected to amqp://guest:**@127.0.0.1:5672//.
[2023-08-03 09:31:45,675: INFO/MainProcess] celery@ip-xx-xx-xx-xx.name-prodc.aio.systems ready.
```

The docker of RabbitMQ also shows as running, but I don't get a log of the tasks I am trying to execute.

When testing it, I created a task in the worker like the following:

```
@celery_app.task(name='test_task')
def test_task(someList):
   print("hello")
   for item in someList:
      infoDB.insert_one(item)
   return "hello"
```

I called this task within one of my API routes in my FastAPI project (test_task.delay(someList), I saw the all the items in "someList" being created in the infoDB, but still the celery queue did not show that the task was received, nor the celery task was stored in the celery_task_meta_data database I have for storing all the messages.

However, when I docker restart rabbitmq (even though that was running) and I execute test_task again. I receive the task and then the celery worker works for a while.

```
2023-08-03 09:31:45,669: INFO/MainProcess] pidbox: Connected to amqp://guest:**@127.0.0.1:5672//.
[2023-08-03 09:31:45,675: INFO/MainProcess] celery@ip-xx-xx-xx-xx.name-prodc.aio.systems ready.
[2023-08-03 09:36:01,796: INFO/MainProcess] Task test_task[d657d20d-2b10-418c-8107-f6f20ed8265c] received
[2023-08-03 09:36:01,796: WARNING/MainProcess] hello
[2023-08-03 09:36:01,797: WARNING/MainProcess] 

[2023-08-03 09:36:01,809: INFO/MainProcess] Task test_task[d657d20d-2b10-418c-8107-f6f20ed8265c] succeeded in 0.012961684027686715s: 'hello'
```

Why does this happen? The test_task seemed to execute but sometimes other tasks don't execute in production and it gets stuck until I don't restart the RabbitMQ docker again. Is there a way to know when that happens to automatically restart the rabbitmq at that moment in time?